# Amazon ACL allow range of ip addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ip-address, acl

I want to allow outbound network traffic from an amazon VPC to ips where the 3rd octet is within a range, so something like 123.456.*.789, where * could be any value.

I do I do this with Amazon's CIDR notation?

I can do 123.456.0.0/16, but that lets the final octet take on any value.

Comment: You might be able to get this feature with a third-party forwarding proxy or gateway solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) is not an AWS thing, it's a widely used standard. You cannot use wildcards in CIDR notation and there's no way to do what you want in a single rule. I'm not sure which specific IPs you're wanting, but note that you wouldn't able to use `x.x.0.n, x.x.1.n ... x.x.255.n` either as that would be 256 total rules. An AWS SG has a hard limit of 100 rules. The `x.x.0.0/16` syntax is the closest you can get.